# UART resistive attenuator not working

Tags: uart

I am trying to establish communications between my Raspberry Pi 1.2b and Arduino Uno.
The Uno received the data sent by the Pi. I know this as I can see it on terminal connected to the Uno.
However it seems it's unable to receive the reply from the Uno.

I attached my FTDI converter to the UART of the Pi, I only see what the pi is sending to the Uno. I don't see anything the Uno is sending to the Pi. I checked the FTDI converter in loopback mode and the Pi in loopback mode. Both are working fine.

I have it wired in the following fashion:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxjint.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I also tried a similar arrangement with a 1k and a 2k. Both combos don't work.

I am using a breadboard and mixture of prefabricated breadboard style wires and DuPont wires. In order to break out into the resistor divider and the transistor arrangement I have to drive the
3.3V to 5V conversion. Could it be one of those situations where breadboards cause your circuit to not work?

I have checked for continuity from the Uno's tx pin to the PI's RX pin. It reads 4.7 kΩ. So that's ok.
I am really confused please help me.

Comment: Have you checked the Uno in loopback mode?

Comment: Put a scope probe on the pi's Rx pin. Do the waveforms look as expected?

Comment: Did you forget to connect the grounds together?

Comment: all grounds are common

Comment: Standard debugging for serial is: try loopback sending (send something, see if it comes back with RX and TX shorted); try the other end's loopback.  check, check, check baud rates.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. What I learned today was always have your grounds tied to a common place. Dont relie on the grounding on the usb connection.  As soon as I added a ground connection the FTDI converter I built, I could see the reply coming from the Uno. Now it's a problem with Node js (software interface)